# Lets Encrypt for private domain?

Tags: openssl, certificates, letsencrypt, certbot

I was wondering is it possible to generate Lets Encrypt certificate for private domains on internal network?

I have my own private DNS running, so I want to apply certificate for my Squid installation. (SSL bump method).

Honestly, I doubt is it possible, but was wondering is there some workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: If its about internal domain why do not use self-signed certificate. Or create own CA?

Comment: Because SSL errors on SSL bumping. Thought LE can bypass this. I already have self-signed certs, just wondering is this possible.

Comment: Yes if the private domain also happens to be a public one, otherwise how would they be able to confirm that you own the domain?

Comment: Create ow CA and add root certificate to the client machines/browsers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

LetsEncrypt needs to verify ownership and it does so via the web, domain names and IP addresses. Internal domains won't work cause they have no way of verifying any of that. You won't have an externally verifiable domain name or IP address.

Comment: Rob : but would it be possible if DDNS is implemented instead, right?

Comment: i don't think so...  it’s would not be possible to issue a cert for a local IP, because everyone could issue a cert for it’s own local IP. So everyone could get a cert and go to your network and intercept all HTTPS connections, [as said rugk](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificates-for-hosts-on-private-networks/174)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as a workaround but you can run a web server and make it public just while certbot runs. After that, you can take it down. So, you can create a script which starts the web server and makes it public, then runs the letsencrypt client and, after that stops it.

Of course, there is a high chance that you cannot/do not want to make your server public even for some seconds, but I cannot think of another viable solution.